# Devise and how to skep sending confirmation letter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to skip sending confirmation letter automatik. I would like to do it manually?
User register himself if he fill in registration form with, name, surname, email, password.
Site admin after validation user, send email manually to his email.
Unless hi confirm email, he cannot log in with "Please confirnm email" message.

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call **skip_confirmation!** before you save the record.

```
@user.skip_confirmation!
@user.save
```

to skip sending confirmation email automatically

and call **send_confirmation_instructions**

```
@user.send_confirmation_instructions
```

to send confirmation manually

Answer (score 1):

Remove the devise :confirmable from user model and the confirmation process for activating user account will be removed. But this will allow users to login once they are signed up. So then you have to do your own validations.

And you can write your own method to send the mail.